# Canvas resizing with getImageData

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm developing an application which allows the user to physically draw onto canvas using touch/stylus. Part of the interface is a 'resize button' which increased the size of the canvas to fill the entire screen to allow for more real-estate.

Currently, I am using getImageData and putImageData to copy the smaller canvas and redraw once the canvas has been enlarged. This works fine...to an extent.

The problem lies when drawing on the larger canvas and reverting back to the smaller canvas, naturally parts of data are cut off. Again, not a problem. But, as I am using getImageData on the canvas itself, if I was to then switch to full-screen AGAIN, it will only copy data that is visible in the smaller canvas. Herein lies the issue.

What I would like is for the drawing data to remain, no matter which view I am in.

Any ideas?

PS. Excuse my strange mix of vanilla and jQuery, I was trying out someone else's suggestion quickly.

Also, `sizer` is the 'resize' button. `draw` is my canvas ID, and `right-panel` wraps my canvas.

```
var panelWidth = $(".right-panel").width();
var panelHeight = $(".right-panel").height();

var c = document.getElementById("draw");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, panelWidth, panelHeight);

$(".sizer").click(function(){
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, panelWidth, panelHeight);
    $('.right-panel').toggleClass('huge');
    var width = $(".right-panel").css("width");
    var height = $(".right-panel").css("height");
    var el = $("canvas");
    el.attr("width", width);
    el.attr("height", height);
    panelWidth = $(".right-panel").css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    panelHeight = $(".right-panel").css("height").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, panelWidth, panelHeight);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Just keep the drawing at as a full resolution canvas, but don't add it to the DOM. Do all the rendering to that canvas and use an onscreen canvas just as a view. This lets you zoom, pan, rotate, resize the view without affecting the drawing. You can draw one canvas onto another using `ctx.drawImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there eventually, correct or not! :) 
What I ended up doing was creating a large canvas initially, and limiting the overflow of it's container. Then, when clicking the 'sizer' icon, effectively revealing the remaining canvas. Simple, but it works.

I attempted `getImageData` and `drawImage()` and neither really worked form me. Maybe I just don't fully understand them! But anyway, in case anyone has a similar issue, thought I'd share.